# Rolling regression by group in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with daily stock returns for individual companies from 1963-2012 (almost 60 million rows). I want to estimate the CAPM betas, so I need to run an rolling OLS regression over the past 250 days for each company and add the beta values to the existing dataframe.

I have already tried to combine the PandasRollingOLS function from the pyfinance package with 'groupby', which only returned a memory error. 
I have also tried to write two for loops, the first one grouping by company ('PERMNO'), the second for loop doing the rolling regression. However, this also does not work

my dataframe looks like this:

```
           PERMNO       RET       mkt       RF
date                                          
1986-01-08  10000 -0.024640 -0.020994  0.00025
1986-01-09  10000 -0.000250 -0.011469  0.00025
1986-01-10  10000 -0.000250 -0.000167  0.00025
1986-01-13  10000  0.049750  0.002499  0.00025
1986-01-14  10000  0.047369  0.000116  0.00025
1986-01-15  10000  0.045205  0.007956  0.00025
1986-01-16  10000  0.043228  0.004452  0.00025
1986-01-17  10000 -0.000250 -0.001991  0.00025
1986-01-20  10000 -0.000250 -0.003985  0.00025
1986-01-21  10000 -0.000250 -0.007242  0.00025
```

```
rolling = daily.groupby('PERMNO').apply(lambda x: ols.PandasRollingOLS(y=daily['RET'], x=daily['mkt'], window=250))
```

```
regression=np.zeros((len(daily.index),2))

for group_name, df_group in daily_grouped:
    for row in range(0,len(daily.index),1):
        y= daily.RET[row:row + 250]
        x= daily.mkt[row:row + 250]
        regression[row]=np.polyfit(x,y,1)

daily['beta']=regression[:,0]
```

I am wondering how to get the beta values from a rolling regression by company

Comment: Not sure if it helps, but have you tried splitting the dataframe per company and load each company individually into memory before applying the OLS? This _might_ avoid the MemoryError.

Comment: I have about 22000 companies, do you have an idea how to load each company in an efficient way?

Comment: Save each company in a separate file and then load one after another. That would be memory efficient, but maybe not performance efficient.

Comment: I think the problem may be that `groupby()` is expected to be followed by some aggregating function, ie. min(), max(), count(), while you want to return a series. Perhaps it would work for you if you take rows of one stock at a time for rolling regression, ie. `daily[daily.PERMNO == 10000].rolling(250).apply(regression_func)`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not very familiar with pyfinance, but [statsmodels.regression.rolling.RollingOLS](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.regression.rolling.RollingOLS.html) works:

```
# Importing
import pandas as pd
from statsmodels.regression.rolling import RollingOLS
import statsmodels.api as sm
import numpy as np

# Creating mock data
permno = []
for i in range(0, 10000):
    permno.append(int(i//2200)+10000)

daily = pd.DataFrame(data={"PERMNO": permno, "RET": np.random.random(10000)*2-1,
                           "mkt": np.random.random(10000)*2-1, "RF": np.random.random(10000)*2-1},
                     index=pd.date_range(start="1963-01-01", periods=10000, freq="B"))

# Rolling OLS calculation
rolling = daily.groupby("PERMNO").apply(lambda x: RollingOLS(endog=x['RET'], exog=sm.add_constant(x['mkt']), window=250).fit().params)
```

Notice that I use `x["dataframe col name"]` not `daily["dataframe col name"]`.  I think this is the cause of the problem, because you use `apply(lambda x:` but haven't then used `x` at all in the computation.  You may be able to change your code from daily to x and find that it works.

I have tried pyfinance, using your rolling calculation, but received the following (which is what occurs with statsmodels RollingOLS when there is no `.fit().params` added to the end to actually return relevant data, suggesting you need a bit more on the end of your code - possibly `.beta` on the end?).  To change your code, if you need the `y=` and `x=`, use something else instead of x, such as `lambda q`, then you can use `y=q['RET'], x=q['mkt']`.

```
#Out: 
#PERMNO
#10000    <pyfinance.ols.PandasRollingOLS object at 0x00...
#10001    <pyfinance.ols.PandasRollingOLS object at 0x00...
#10002    <pyfinance.ols.PandasRollingOLS object at 0x00...
#10003    <pyfinance.ols.PandasRollingOLS object at 0x00...
#10004    <pyfinance.ols.PandasRollingOLS object at 0x00...
#dtype: object
```