# Rolling OLS Regressions and Predictions by Group

Tags: python, dataframe, pandas-groupby, statsmodels, rolling-computation

I have a Pandas dataframe with some data on race car drivers. The relevant columns look like this:

```
|Date    |Name     |Distance   |avg_speed_calc  
|----    |----     |----       |----         
|9/6/20  | Smith   | 8         | 85.6
|9/6/20  | Douglas | 8         | 84.9
|9/6/20  | Mostern | 8         | 84.3

.......

|Date    |Name      |Distance  |avg_speed_calc 
|:----   |:----     |:-----    |:----         
|4/5/21  | Smith    | 6        | 88.7
|4/5/21  | Robinson | 6        | 89.3
|4/5/21  | Thomas   | 6        | 87.5
```

In the data above, each race has a variable number of participants, and not every racer competes in every event - some may even have only one row entry.

I'm trying to make a simple OLS to get an idea of each racer's preferred distance by regressing only distance against his average_speed_calc. Because I want the calculation to update following every race, I have been trying to utilize RollingOLS from StatsModels. With the help of a somewhat [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56457085/rolling-regression-by-group-in-pandas-dataframe) a few years ago, my code currently looks like this:

```
from statsmodels.regression.rolling import RollingOLS
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


dist_pref = df.groupby(["Name"]).apply(lambda x: RollingOLS(endog=x['avg_speed_calc'], exog=sm.add_constant(x['Distance']),min_nobs=2)).fit().params)
```

However, this throws the message "ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (0) into shape (1)", which I have thus far not been able to fix.

I have also tried a helper function, based on [another old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24544805/python-pandas-how-to-run-multiple-univariate-regression-by-group), to no avail:

```
def ols_res(x, y):
    return pd.Series(RollingOLS(y, x).fit().predict)

df_dist = df.groupby(['Name']).apply(lambda x : x['Distance'].apply(ols_res, y=x['avg_speed_calc']))
```

Ideally, I would want to then predict the average_speed_calc for that day's race, using only the data from prior races, so that I can compare it to the actual avg_speed_calc reported in that row. I thought to create separate DataFrame columns for each coefficient/intercept, then shift them down one, and then use those numbers along with the distance of the current race to make the prediction, but perhaps there is a more efficient way.

Assuming the resulting dataframe is then sorted by date and racer, my desired final output (which requires two or more prior races for the prediction) is a dataframe with info for each racer as follows:

| Date | Name | Distance | avg_speed_calc | predicted_speed_calc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 9/6/20 | Smith | 8 | 85.6 | nan |
| 11/15/20 | Smith | 6 | 82.6 | nan |
| 1/4/21 | Smith | 7 | 83.4 | 84.1 |
| 2/20/21 | Smith | 7 | 82.9 | 83.9 |
| 4/5/21 | Smith | 8.5 | 84.8 | 85.7 |

Having another column with the standard error of the predicted_speed_calc would also be nice, but that's a secondary issue I'll sort out later. Thanks in advance for any guidance and suggestions on the above.

EDIT 2:

Thanks to @LarryBird, I now have a workable function for the rolling linear OLS result. However, if possible I would like to also try one for a 2nd degree polynomial fit by using the 'from_formula' method, as well as return the residuals to compare them to the linear fit.

I am trying to fit the quadratic equation based on the info [here](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/examples/notebooks/generated/formulas.html) and the 'speed_preference_from_formula' function defined below. However, if I try to refer to the same column twice (i.e. using 'avg_speed_calc ~ Distance + Distance**2', 'params' returns only two columns instead of the expected three. I have made a helper column for the squared value (see below), but the coefficients returned are clearly inaccurate so I know I'm doing something wrong.

```
import numpy.polynomial.polynomial as poly
import patsy

df['Distance2']  = df['Distance']**2
grouped2 = df.groupby('Name')
form = "avg_speed_calc ~ Distance + Distance2"
params2 = grouped2.apply(lambda x: speed_preference_from_formula(x, form, 4))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to achieve what you want using the groupby / apply pattern. The below code should be helpful.

**Create example data:**

```
from statsmodels.regression.rolling import RollingOLS
from statsmodels.tools.tools import add_constant
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# make some toy data
race_dates = pd.to_datetime(['2020-06-09']*3 + ['2020-12-01']*4 + ['2021-01-21']*4 + ['2021-05-04']*5)
distance = [8]*3 + [7]*4 + [4]*4 + [6]*5
avg_speed = 80 + np.random.randn(len(distance))*10
names = ['Smith', 'Douglas', 'Mostern',
         'Smith', 'Douglas', 'Mostern', 'Robinson',
         'Smith', 'Douglas', 'Mostern', 'Robinson',
         'Smith', 'Douglas', 'Mostern', 'Robinson', 'Thomas']

df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': race_dates,
                  'Name': names,
                  'Distance': distance,
                  'avg_speed_calc': avg_speed})
```

**Define helper functions:**

```
def speed_preference(df_racer, intercept=False):
    """
    Function to operate on the data of a single driver.
    Assumes df_racer has the columns 'Distance' and 'avg_speed_calc' available.
    Returns a dataframe containing model parameters
    """
    # we should have atleast (number_of_parameters) + 1 observations
    min_obs = 3 if intercept else 2

    # if there are less than min_obs rows in df_racer, RollingOLS will throw an error
    # Instead, handle this case separately
    if df_racer.shape[0] < min_obs:
        cols = ['const', 'Distance'] if intercept else ['Distance']
        return pd.DataFrame(index=df_racer.index, columns=cols)
    
    y = df_racer['avg_speed_calc']
    x = add_constant(df_racer['Distance']) if intercept else df_racer['Distance']
    
    model = RollingOLS(y, x, expanding=True, min_nobs=min_obs).fit()
    return model.params


def speed_prediction(df_racer, intercept=False):
    """
    Function to operate on the data of a single driver.
    Assumes df_racer has the columns 'Distance' and 'avg_speed_calc' available.
    Returns a series containing predicted speed
    """
    params = speed_preference(df_racer, intercept)
    params_shifted = params.shift(1)
    
    if intercept:
        return (params_shifted.mul(add_constant(df_racer['Distance']), axis=0)\
                .sum(axis=1, min_count=1)).to_frame('predicted_speed_calc')
    
    return (params_shifted.mul(df_racer['Distance'], axis=0))\
                .rename({'Distance': 'predicted_speed_calc'}, axis=1)
```

The `speed_preference` function computes the rolling OLS for a single driver, and return the fitted parameter(s). The `speed_prediction` function computes the predicted speed, using the model up the previous race (notice `params_shifted`) as requested. To put it all together, just a simple groupby and join is required:

**No intercept**

```
grouped = df.groupby('Name')
params = grouped.apply(speed_preference)
predictions = grouped.apply(speed_prediction)

df_out_no_intercept = df.join(params, rsuffix='_coef').join(predictions)
df_out_no_intercept
```

[image: output no intercept]

**With intercept**

```
grouped = df.groupby('Name')
params = grouped.apply(lambda x: speed_preference(x, True))
predictions = grouped.apply(lambda x: speed_prediction(x, True))

df_out_w_intercept = df.join(params, rsuffix='_coef').join(predictions)
df_out_w_intercept
```

[image: output with intercept]

**EDIT**

If you would like to fit a model from formula instead, you could use:

```
def speed_preference_from_formula(df_racer, formula, min_nobs):
    """
    Function to operate on the data of a single driver. "formula" should reference column names in df_racer.
    min_nobs should always be >= (# of parameters in the model)+1
    """
    
    # if there are less than min_obs rows in df_racer, RollingOLS will throw an error
    # Instead, handle this case separately
    if df_racer.shape[0] < min_nobs:

        return None
    model = RollingOLS.from_formula(formula, data=df_racer, expanding=True, min_nobs=min_nobs, window=None).fit()
    return model.params
```

Then for a polynomial model, you could compute the parameters as follows:

```
grouped = df.groupby('Name')
formula = "avg_speed_calc ~ 1 + Distance + Distance^2"
grouped.apply(lambda x: speed_preference_from_formula(x, formula, 4))
```

Output:

[image: output 3]

Note you would need to also edit the speed prediction function to handle the parameters and generated predictions correctly.

Notice that in the formula, I reference column names present in the dataframe being passed in. The `1` indicates an intercept should be used (similar to sm.add_constant), the `Distance` means use the value in `Distance` column directly, and the `Distance^2` means square the value in `Distance` column, and then use that value as a feature. If you wanted to fit a cubic model, you can add the term `+ Distance^3`.

For a good reference on how to use thes "R-style" formulas, see [here](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/examples/notebooks/generated/formulas.html).

**EDIT 2: On debugging groupby**

Think of the `groupby.apply` pattern as simply splitting the dataframe into multiple smaller dataframes, applying some function to each of the dataframes individually, and then joining back together. To see each sub-dataframe that is generated by the groupby, you can use:

```
grouped = df.groupby('Name')
for name, group in grouped:
    print(f"The sub-dataframe for: {name}")
    print(group)
```

This is useful, because you can now see exactly what gets passed to the function you are using inside the `.apply()`.

So for the error mentioned in comments, you can apply the function to each group individually to narrow down where the error is occurring.

Comment: Thank you very, very much for your answer - it was extremely helpful. Everything works until the last step - when I try to run "df_out_w_intercept", it throws "ValueError: cannot join with no overlapping index names". Any idea why this might be or how I can quickly fix it? Thanks again.

Comment: @AMJ It runs for me without a problem. Can you please provide more details on your error? What does `df.index`, `params.index` and `predictions.index` return?

Comment: df.index returns an Int64 index, params.index returns a MultiIndex with  (Name, Index #), and predictions.index returns a MultiIndex with (Name, Index #)

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. What is `pd.__version__`? Also, are you sure `df` has not been modified before you pass to the second groupby?

Comment: My pd.__version__ is '1.1.2'. I think it must be some problem with this, because when I copied and pasted your exact code into a new, blank notebook (I'm using Jupyter), I get the same 'ValueError: cannot join with no overlapping index names' error.. I will wait to hear back from you before updating anything though. Thanks again, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Hmm yeah seems likely related to different pandas version. I am on 1.3.2. I don't have time right now to downgrade and try to reproduce your error. I can suggest two things:
(1) It seems like the groupby is returning an extra level of index, which is causing issue for the join. You can try to drop a level of the multiindex before doing the join with `df.droplevel(0)` on  params and predictions. If you edit your question showing exactly what `df`, `params` and `predictions` looks like before you do the join I can probably give you some better advice.  (2) Upgrade your pandas

Comment: Applying df.droplevel(0) to both predictions & params did the trick! One more question - if I wanted to experiment with the predictions from a logistic OLS (as I think certain racers have a 'peak' preference and experience avg. speed declines at distances both longer and shorter than it) instead of the linear ones here, is there any way the code above could be easily modified, such as by using sm.regression.rolling.RollingOLS.from_formula? If you don't have the time or desire to look into this any futher though no worries, you have already helped me enough. Thx again, best bball player ever!

Comment: @AMJ sorry for the delay. I missed your comment last week. Firstly, logistic regression may not be appropriate in this situation, since it's predictions are bounded between 0 and 1 (it is usually used to model binary outcomes or probabilities). That said, more generally yes, you can use other model structures as specified via a `statsmodels.formula.api` formula. To make this work, I would suggest for you to modify the `speed_preference` function so that it accepts a formula as an argument. I encourage you to give it a go yourself, but if you edit your question I can provide example for you.

Comment: No problem at all, it was the weekend anyway! Sorry, I didn’t mean logistic regression – I should have said a polynomial fit (just quadratic should be fine). I have been messing around with the formula all day, but it always throws one error or another, and there are no examples I can find online of making a custom structure for usage in a RollingOLS. I have updated my question above, any guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks again.

Comment: I have edited my answer demonstrating how to specify a quadratic model using "from_formula". You should read the link I added at the bottom to understand in more detail what is going on. I hope it is helpful. Looking at your attempts, I would suggest it may be worth going back to basics to properly understand what these models are doing. If my answer has been helpful to you, please don't forget to accept it :). And I am glad you appreciate the Larry Legend reference.

Comment: I’ve accepted your answer as you’ve already given me more help than I could have hoped for. I can’t replicate your result though – I made another edit above. My attempt to alter the ‘speed_prediction_from_formula’ is also throwing a ‘'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shift' error. You are correct, I am in over my head with these functions - I fully follow the linear one but the quadratic one has been an issue. Any help appreciated, and Celts in 6 :)

Comment: Ah yes this error is probably caused by the `df_racer.shape[0] < min_nob` case, where the speed preference function returns `None`. You can put a guard clause in - `if params is None: # do something`.
I will add one more edit to my answer with some advice on how to understand what is happening inside the groupby, hopefully it can help you more generally.

Comment: Is there any chance you can post the code that created the polynomial output dataframe shown above? I honestly hate asking, but I'm on a deadline and this problem has put me behind schedule -__- I'm even willing to pay for it if I have to

Comment: I did post it? The output image I posted underneath the first edit section, is created by calling `grouped = df.groupby('Name')` followed by `grouped.apply(lambda x: speed_preference_from_formula(x, formula, 4))`

Comment: ohhh I realise I didn't post the formula! I will add to my answer now

Comment: Adding the '1 +' term fixed it! Thanks again, Larry Legend forever!!

Comment: You were nearly right with the C's in 6 ... just took them one extra game. Goodluck with your deadline!