# Rolling Regression Residuals Python

Tags: python, lambda, regression, statsmodels, rolling-computation

I hope you can help me with my problem. I want to do a rolling regression on a dataframe in Python and calculate the standard deviation on only a part of the residuals.

For example: in the table below I want to estimate parameters based on a moving window (e.g. Y = [5,7,9,10] on X_1 = [1,2,4,5] and X_2 =[2,3,4,4] which results in intercept = 2.4 and B_1 = 0.7 and B_2 = 1. These estimators lead to residuals = [4.8,0.5,-0.2,-0.2] of which the standard deviation is measured based on the last 3 residuals [0.5,-0.2,-0.2], which should be passet to the column ["standard deviation"]

| Index | Y | X_1 | X_2 | Standard deviation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 5 | 1 | 2 | 0.404145188 |
| 1 | 7 | 2 | 3 | 2.081665999 |
| 2 | 9 | 4 | 4 | 2.511132239 |
| 3 | 10 | 5 | 4 | 0.864408264 |
| 4 | 11 | 6 | 2 | nan |
| 5 | 14 | 5 | 5 | nan |
| 6 | 17 | 7 | 6 | nan |

My original dataset is huge, so I tried to avoid a for loop.
My approach so far is to either do a regression in each row, using the following function (which does not result in the :

import statsmodels.api as sm

```
df["Standard deviation"] = df.rolling(window = 4).apply(lambda x: (df["Y"]-sm.OLS(df["Y"],df["X_1"]&df["X_2").fit().predict()).std())
```

However, the function only works on the entire column - so it is not a rolling regression and I could not find a way to only calculate the standard deviation based on the last 3 residuals.

Comment: Can you please provide a [minimum reproduceable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It will help others help you.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You can't get there easily using `rolling(36).apply` since it operated column by column.  You should look at `numpy_ext` and `rolling_apply`.

Comment: Thank you very much! Numpy_ext and rolling_apply solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

Below is a working example with RollingOLS from statsmodels. The inspiration is from the [answer to this question on Rolling OLS Regressions and Predictions by Group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72119449/rolling-ols-regressions-and-predictions-by-group).

```py
from statsmodels.regression.rolling import RollingOLS
from statsmodels.tools.tools import add_constant
import statsmodels.api as sm
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = sm.datasets.grunfeld.load()
df_grunfeld = pd.DataFrame(data.data)
df_grunfeld.set_index(['firm'], append=True, inplace=True)

# Simple Model
# $$invest = \beta_0 + \beta_1 value$$

def invest_params(df_gf, intercept=False):

    """
    Function to operate on the data of a single firm.
    Assumes df_gf has the columns 'invest' and 'value' available.
    Returns a dataframe containing model parameters
    """

    # we should have at least k + 1 observations
    min_obs = 3 if intercept else 2
    wndw = 8 

    # if there are fewer than min_obs rows in df_gf, RollingOLS will throw an error
    # Instead, handle this case separately

    if df_gf.shape[0] < min_obs:
        cols = ['coef_intercept', 'coef_value'] if intercept else ['coef_value']
        return pd.DataFrame(index=df_gf.index, columns=cols)

    y = df_gf['invest']
    x = add_constant(df_gf['value']) if intercept else df_gf['value']

    model = RollingOLS(y, x, expanding=True, min_nobs=min_obs, window=wndw).fit()

    parameters = model.params
    params_shifted = model.params.shift(1)
    mse = model.mse_resid
    parameters['invest_hat'] = (parameters.mul(add_constant(df_gf['value']), axis=0)\
                                .sum(axis=1, min_count=1)).to_frame('invest_hat')

    parameters['invest_hat_shift'] = (params_shifted.mul(add_constant(df_gf['value']), axis=0)\
                                      .sum(axis=1, min_count=1)).to_frame('invest_hat_shift')

    parameters['mse'] = mse
    parameters['rmse'] = np.sqrt(mse)
    parameters['nobs'] = model.nobs
    parameters['ssr'] = model.ssr
    parameters['t_const'] = model.tvalues['const']
    parameters['t_value'] = model.tvalues['value']
    parameters.rename(columns = {'const' : 'b0', 'value' : 'b1'}, inplace = True)
    parameters['r2_adj'] = model.rsquared_adj
    
    return parameters

grouped = df_grunfeld.groupby('firm')
df_params = grouped.apply(lambda x: invest_params(x, True))
df_grunfeld_output = df_grunfeld.join(df_params, rsuffix='_coef')
```