# Rolling Window Regression

Tags: python, group-by, least-squares, rolling-computation, standard-error

I need to compute rolling window regressions in Python where the standard errors are corrected for HAC (Newey-West, 1987). I know that statsmodels has a function for rolling window regressions (Rolling Regression), but the standard errors cannot be corrected for HAC in this function. Therefore I have defined my own function.

I have a panel data set with 108,768 rows (410 unique funds) and the structure looks as follows:

```
funds = pd.DataFrame({
    "Fund": ["A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B"], 
    "Excess_Return": [np.NaN, 0.172, 0.0465, 0.039, 0.003995, -0.022139, 0.009518, 0.03233],
    "Regression_Constant": [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1], 
    "RMRF": [0.0118,0.0557,0.0129,0.0403,0.0118,0.0557,0.0129,0.0403], 
    "SMB": [0.0445,0.1838,-0.1539,-0.0496,0.0445,0.1838,-0.1539,-0.0496], 
    "HML": [-0.0189,-0.0981,0.0823,0.0725,-0.0189,-0.0981,0.0823,0.0725], 
    "RMW": [-0.0629,-0.1876,0.1182,0.0767,-0.0629,-0.1876,0.1182,0.0767], 
    "CMA": [0.0474,-0.0035,-0.0161,0.0562,0.0474,-0.0035,-0.0161,0.0562]})
```

The function is defined as follows:

```
min_t = 30

t = 36

def process(x):
    if x["Excess_Return"].count() >= min_t:
        reg = smf.ols("Excess_Return ~ RMRF + SMB + HML + RMW + CMA", data = x).fit(cov_type="HAC", cov_kwds={"maxlags":1})
        return [
            reg.params[0],
            reg.params["RMRF"],
            reg.params["SMB"],
            reg.params["HML"],
            reg.params["RMW"],
            reg.params["CMA"],
            # tvalues
            reg.tvalues[0],
            reg.tvalues["RMRF"],
            reg.tvalues["SMB"],
            reg.tvalues["HML"],
            reg.tvalues["RMW"],
            reg.tvalues["CMA"],

        ]
    # Else return NaN
    return [np.nan] * 10
```

To run the function and get the results in a data frame i run the following command:

```
df_1 = funds.join(
    # join new DataFrame back to original
    pd.DataFrame(
        (process(x) for x in funds.rolling(t)),
        columns=["alpha", "Beta_RMRF", "Beta_SMB", "Beta_HML", "Beta_RMW", "Beta_CMA",
                 "t_alpha", "t_RMRF", "t_SMB", "t_HML", "t_RMW", "t_CMA"]
    )
)
```

This returns the correct t-stats of the regressions. However, since I have multiple funds, I need to group the funds by their name, i.e. that the returns of fund A are not taken into account when running regressions for fund B. Does anybody have a solution how to rearrange the code?

Comment: It does not work that way. (1) you miss the `return` output of the function. (2) if you want to do the rolling regression then I suggest you to visit this link: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.window.rolling.Rolling.apply.html

Comment: Many thanks for your reply. The question is now edited. The function is now working properly. The last problem I have is the grouping of funds. Do you have an idea regarding this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Below is a working example with RollingOLS from statsmodels. The inspiration is from the [answer to this question on Rolling OLS Regressions and Predictions by Group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72119449/rolling-ols-regressions-and-predictions-by-group).

This can easily be modified for your panel data to perform a rolling window regression. Specify the covariance structure in `model.fit()`. See https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.regression.rolling.RollingOLS.fit.html#statsmodels.regression.rolling.RollingOLS.fit.

```py
from statsmodels.regression.rolling import RollingOLS
from statsmodels.tools.tools import add_constant
import statsmodels.api as sm
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = sm.datasets.grunfeld.load()
df_grunfeld = pd.DataFrame(data.data)
df_grunfeld.set_index(['firm'], append=True, inplace=True)

# Simple Model
# $$invest = \beta_0 + \beta_1 value$$

def invest_params(df_gf, intercept=False):

    """
    Function to operate on the data of a single firm.
    Assumes df_gf has the columns 'invest' and 'value' available.
    Returns a dataframe containing model parameters
    """

    # we should have at least k + 1 observations
    min_obs = 3 if intercept else 2
    wndw = 8 

    # if there are less than min_obs rows in df_gf, RollingOLS will throw an error
    # Instead, handle this case separately

    if df_gf.shape[0] < min_obs:
        cols = ['coef_intercept', 'coef_value'] if intercept else ['coef_value']
        return pd.DataFrame(index=df_gf.index, columns=cols)

    y = df_gf['invest']
    x = add_constant(df_gf['value']) if intercept else df_gf['value']

    model = RollingOLS(y, x, expanding=True, min_nobs=min_obs, window=wndw).fit()

    parameters = model.params
    params_shifted = model.params.shift(1)
    mse = model.mse_resid
    parameters['invest_hat'] = (parameters.mul(add_constant(df_gf['value']), axis=0)\
                                .sum(axis=1, min_count=1)).to_frame('invest_hat')

    parameters['invest_hat_shift'] = (params_shifted.mul(add_constant(df_gf['value']), axis=0)\
                                      .sum(axis=1, min_count=1)).to_frame('invest_hat_shift')

    parameters['mse'] = mse
    parameters['rmse'] = np.sqrt(mse)
    parameters['nobs'] = model.nobs
    parameters['ssr'] = model.ssr
    parameters['t_const'] = model.tvalues['const']
    parameters['t_value'] = model.tvalues['value']
    parameters.rename(columns = {'const' : 'b0', 'value' : 'b1'}, inplace = True)
    parameters['r2_adj'] = model.rsquared_adj
    
    return parameters

grouped = df_grunfeld.groupby('firm')
df_params = grouped.apply(lambda x: invest_params(x, True))
df_grunfeld_output = df_grunfeld.join(df_params, rsuffix='_coef')
```