# How to implement Rolling Regression in Python

Tags: python, pandas, regression

I'm trying to predict the Adjusted Closing Price for the next day for a stock using Rolling Regression.

```
       Open       High        Low          Close    Adj Close   
0   26.629999   27.000000   26.290001   26.600000   26.599386   
1   26.670000   27.450001   26.540001   27.350000   27.349369   
2   27.340000   27.440001   26.889999   27.139999   27.139374   
3   27.070000   27.420000   26.969999   27.280001   27.279371   
4   26.700001   27.190001   26.459999   27.129999   27.129374
```

Every row in my database is a trading day.

So here I have a window of 5, trying to predict W + 1 (the price for the 6th day)

I've tried using statsmodel RollingOLS and have this so far

```
df_20['const'] = 1

model = RollingOLS(endog =df_20['Adj Close'].values , exog=df_20[['Open', 'Close']],window=5)
rres = model.fit()

rres.params
```

Where the manual told me to add a constant, so I added '1'.

This isn't working, my code comes out like this.

```
    Open         Close
-4.428939e-07   0.999977
1.411571e-07    0.999977
4.341009e-07    0.999976
3.469735e-07    0.999977
3.208869e-07    0.999977
```

Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could transform your window into separate columns, like so:

```py
# == Necessary Imports ====================================
# Note: to install ``sklearn`` run: ``pip install scikit-learn``

import pandas as pd
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn import linear_model

# == Sample DataFrame ====================================

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'Open': [
            26.629999,
            26.670000,
            27.340000,
            27.070000,
            26.700001
        ],
        'High': [
            27.000000,
            27.450001,
            27.440001,
            27.420000,
            27.190001
        ],
        'Low': [
            26.290001,
            26.540001,
            26.889999,
            26.969999,
            26.459999
        ],
        'Close': [
            26.600000,
            27.350000,
            27.139999,
            27.280001,
            27.129999
        ],
        'Adj Close': [
            26.599386,
            27.349369,
            27.139374,
            27.279371,
            27.129374
        ],
    }
)

# == Transform Window on ``n`` days into columns ========
window_size = 3
new_df = df.iloc[window_size:].copy()
row_count, column_count = df.shape


for index, row in new_df.iterrows():
    for i in range(1, window_size+1):
        for column in df.columns:
            new_df.loc[new_df.index == index, f'{column}_D-{i}'] = df.iloc[index - i][column]

# == Separate the Target column from the rest of the columns ======
# Note: perform a ``train_test_split`` when running this code for real

y = new_df.pop('Adj Close')
X = new_df

# == Normalize the data and train the model ========================
scaler = StandardScaler()
reg = linear_model.LinearRegression()

# Normalizing the data
X_norm = scaler.fit_transform(X.values)

# Training a linear regression model
reg = reg.fit(X_norm, y)

# Adding predictions back to the "original" dataframe
new_df['Predicted Adj Close'] = reg.predict(X_norm)

new_df
# Returns:
#         Open       High        Low      Close  Open_D-1   High_D-1    Low_D-1  \
# 3  27.070000  27.420000  26.969999  27.280001     27.34  27.440001  26.889999   
# 4  26.700001  27.190001  26.459999  27.129999     27.07  27.420000  26.969999   

#    Close_D-1  Adj Close_D-1  Open_D-2   High_D-2    Low_D-2  Close_D-2  \
# 3  27.139999      27.139374     26.67  27.450001  26.540001  27.350000   
# 4  27.280001      27.279371     27.34  27.440001  26.889999  27.139999   

#    Adj Close_D-2   Open_D-3   High_D-3    Low_D-3  Close_D-3  Adj Close_D-3  \
# 3      27.349369  26.629999  27.000000  26.290001      26.60      26.599386   
# 4      27.139374  26.670000  27.450001  26.540001      27.35      27.349369   

#    Predicted Adj Close  
# 3            27.279371  
# 4            27.129374
```

**Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Below is a working example with RollingOLS from statsmodels. The inspiration is from the [answer to this question on Rolling OLS Regressions and Predictions by Group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72119449/rolling-ols-regressions-and-predictions-by-group).

For the constant (aka intercept), use `add_constant()`, as in the example below.

For the prediction, use `shift()`, also in the example below.

```py
from statsmodels.regression.rolling import RollingOLS
from statsmodels.tools.tools import add_constant
import statsmodels.api as sm
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = sm.datasets.grunfeld.load()
df_grunfeld = pd.DataFrame(data.data)
df_grunfeld.set_index(['firm'], append=True, inplace=True)

# Simple Model
# $$invest = \beta_0 + \beta_1 value$$

def invest_params(df_gf, intercept=False):

    """
    Function to operate on the data of a single firm.
    Assumes df_gf has the columns 'invest' and 'value' available.
    Returns a dataframe containing model parameters
    """

    # we should have at least k + 1 observations
    min_obs = 3 if intercept else 2
    wndw = 8 

    # if there are less than min_obs rows in df_gf, RollingOLS will throw an error
    # Instead, handle this case separately

    if df_gf.shape[0] < min_obs:
        cols = ['coef_intercept', 'coef_value'] if intercept else ['coef_value']
        return pd.DataFrame(index=df_gf.index, columns=cols)

    y = df_gf['invest']
    x = add_constant(df_gf['value']) if intercept else df_gf['value']

    model = RollingOLS(y, x, expanding=True, min_nobs=min_obs, window=wndw).fit()

    parameters = model.params
    params_shifted = model.params.shift(1)
    mse = model.mse_resid
    parameters['invest_hat'] = (parameters.mul(add_constant(df_gf['value']), axis=0)\
                                .sum(axis=1, min_count=1)).to_frame('invest_hat')

    parameters['invest_hat_shift'] = (params_shifted.mul(add_constant(df_gf['value']), axis=0)\
                                      .sum(axis=1, min_count=1)).to_frame('invest_hat_shift')

    parameters['mse'] = mse
    parameters['rmse'] = np.sqrt(mse)
    parameters['nobs'] = model.nobs
    parameters['ssr'] = model.ssr
    parameters['t_const'] = model.tvalues['const']
    parameters['t_value'] = model.tvalues['value']
    parameters.rename(columns = {'const' : 'b0', 'value' : 'b1'}, inplace = True)
    parameters['r2_adj'] = model.rsquared_adj
    
    return parameters

grouped = df_grunfeld.groupby('firm')
df_params = grouped.apply(lambda x: invest_params(x, True))
df_grunfeld_output = df_grunfeld.join(df_params, rsuffix='_coef')
```