# Pandas statsmodels Regression with Rolling dynamic window

Tags: python, pandas, dynamic, regression, statsmodels

Goal: I want to calculate regression coefficient and intercept per code using statsmodels package.

Problem: dynamic window is not working.

See below sample data.

```
d={'code':['A','A','A','A','B','B','B','C','C','C'],
   'Price':[10,8,11,13,1.1,1.3,1.5,100,101,104],
   'group_index':[1,2,3,4,1,2,3,1,2,3],
   'index_start':[1,1,2,2,1,1,2,1,1,1]}
df_dynamic_window=pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

[image]

Actual dataset is accumulating and have lots of different code. calculating regression code by code probably not a good idea.

Below code is statsmodels rolling regression with fixed window value and it is working properly.

```
(   
df_dynamic_window
  .groupby('code', group_keys=True)
  .apply(
      lambda x: RollingOLS(
          endog=x['Price'], 
          exog=sm.add_constant(x['group_index']), 
          window=10
          #window=x['group_index']-x['index_start'] <<--- This is NOT working
      )
  .fit()
  .params
)
```

If I will use the dynamic_window, I'll get an error:
TypeError: window must be integer_like (int or np.integer, but not bool or timedelta64) or None.
Note that I already change dtype to int.

I tried another approach but didnt suceed. see below:

```
def regression(row):
   code = row['code']
   start = row['index_start']
   end = row['group_index']

   table = df_dynamic_window.loc[(df_dynamic_window['code'] == code) &
                              (df_dynamic_window['group_index'] >= start ) & 
                              (df_dynamic_window['group_index'] <= end)]

   y= table['Price']
   X= table['index_start']
   OLS = sm.OLS(y, X).fit().params

   return OLS

df_dynamic_window.groupby('code', group_keys=True).apply(regression)
```

The above gives me error about: ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects

Im currently stock on this problem. Appreciate your help and advise.

Answer (score 0):

The package `statsmodels` has a module/method `RollingOLS` that should solve your problem.

Here are two examples with that accomplish what you are seeking.

[Can I vary the window on a rolling regression using python's RollingOLS from statsmodels?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75749109/can-i-vary-the-window-on-a-rolling-regression-using-pythons-rollingols-from-sta)

[Rolling OLS Regressions and Predictions by Group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72119449/rolling-ols-regressions-and-predictions-by-group)

For the sake of a direct, self-contained answer to your question, see my copypasta below.

```py
from statsmodels.regression.rolling import RollingOLS
from statsmodels.tools.tools import add_constant
import statsmodels.api as sm
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = sm.datasets.grunfeld.load()
df_grunfeld = pd.DataFrame(data.data)
df_grunfeld.set_index(['firm'], append=True, inplace=True)
df_grunfeld['window'] = np.random.randint(3, 6, df_grunfeld.shape[0])

def invest_preference(df_gf, intercept=False):
    """
    Function to operate on the data of a single firm.
    Assumes df_gf has the columns 'invest' and 'value' available.
    Returns a dataframe containing model parameters
    """
    # we should have at least k + 1 observations
    min_obs = 3 if intercept else 2
    wndw = 4
    
    # if there are fewer than min_obs rows in df_gf, RollingOLS will throw an error
    # Instead, handle this case separately
    if df_gf.shape[0] < min_obs:
        cols = ['const', 'value'] if intercept else ['value']
        return pd.DataFrame(index=df_gf.index, columns=cols)
    
    y = df_gf['invest']
    x = add_constant(df_gf['value']) if intercept else df_gf['value']
    
    model = RollingOLS(y, x, expanding=True, min_nobs=min_obs, window=wndw).fit()
    return model.params

def invest_prediction(df_gf, intercept=False):
    """
    Function to operate on the data of a single firm.
    Assumes df_gf has the columns 'invest' and 'value' available.
    Returns a series containing predicted invest
    """
    params = invest_preference(df_gf, intercept)
    params_shifted = params.shift(1)
    
    if intercept:
        return (params_shifted.mul(add_constant(df_gf['value']), axis=0)\
                .sum(axis=1, min_count=1)).to_frame('predicted_invest_calc')
    
    return (params_shifted.mul(df_gf['value'], axis=0))\
                .rename({'value': 'predicted_invest_calc'}, axis=1)

grouped = df_grunfeld.groupby('firm')
df_params = grouped.apply(lambda x: invest_preference(x, True))
df_predictions = grouped.apply(lambda x: invest_prediction(x, True))
df_out_w_intercept = df_grunfeld.join(df_params, rsuffix='_coef').join(df_predictions)
```